# How to make a asynchronous web api call from asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement **asynchronous web api** call from **asp.net**

My code is similar like this

```
var response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/apicontroller/execute/", executeModel).Result;
```

This is working in **synchronous mode**.

I do not want to wait for my **webapi call** to complete.
How I can implement this using **.net framework 4**?

Answer (score 2):

Change the line to:

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/apicontroller/execute/", executeModel);
```

Checking the `Result` property makes it synchronous. Also make sure your method signature contains the `async` keyword.

*edit:* If you don't want to wait for the result right away, you can postpone the await like this (or never perform it):

```
var task = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/apicontroller/execute/", executeModel);
/* Do other stuff in parallell here */
var result = await task;
```

Answer (score 1):

> How I can implement this using .net framework 4?

You can't use `async`, `await`, or `HttpClient` on ASP.NET 4. They all [require ASP.NET 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx). Your options are to upgrade to ASP.NET 4.5 and use the natural `await` syntax or to stay on ASP.NET 4 and use something like `WebClient`.

Comment: There's also the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package on NuGet, if you're using .NET 4.0 in VS2012.

Comment: @DanielMann: No. `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` is not supported on ASP.NET. It's only for desktop/mobile/store projects.